# Working example of secp256k1 key generation and sign/verify in freepascal

Tags: cryptography, freepascal

Im developing a criptocurrency engine using freepascal/lazarus. I used OpenSSL to create key pairs using TProcess calls; same to sign and verify messages using secp256k1.

Now i found this library: https://github.com/Xor-el/CryptoLib4Pascal

Which seems to be able to do that, so i could eliminate dependency from OpenSSL, reduces the time of processing in nearly 98% and make it automatically cross-plattform.
Even when the lybrary includes some examples, im unable to find the way to get a working functions for this:

```
Keyspair= Packed Record
     public: String[255];
     private: String[255];
     end;  

Var
MyKeysPair: Keyspair;
MyMessage : string = 'Hello world';
Begin
Keyspair := GenerateKeys('secp256k1');
End;

Function GenerateKeys(algo:string):Keyspair;
Begin
// Stuff from CryptoLib4Pascal...
result.public := ???;
result.private := ???;
End;
```

Then, with the keys pair sign and verify the message:

```
var
SignedMessage: string;
Begin
SignedMessage := GetSignedMessage(Keyspair.private,MyMessage);
if VerifySignature(MyMessage,SignedMessage,Keyspair.public) then writeln('Perfect');
End;

function GetSignedMessage(PrivKey,Message:String):String;
Begin
// Stuff from CryptoLib4Pascal...
result := ???;
End;

function VerifySignature(Message,Signature,PubKey:string):boolean;
Begin
Result:= false;
if {stuff from CryptoLib4Pascal} then result := true;
End;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    var
    LSecureRandom     : ISecureRandom;
    LCustomCurve      : IX9ECParameters;
    LECDomainParams   : IECDomainParameters;
      LKeyPairGenerator : IECKeyPairGenerator;
      LKeyGenParams     : IECKeyGenerationParameters;
      LKeyPair          : IAsymmetricCipherKeyPair;
      LPrivateKeyParams : IECPrivateKeyParameters;
      LPublicKeyParams  : IECPublicKeyParameters;
    
      PrivKey, PubKey, KoordX, KoordY,
      PubKeyUnCompressed, PubKeyCompressed : String;

    begin
      LSecureRandom     := TSecureRandom.Create(); // OSRandom Mode
      LCustomCurve      := TCustomNamedCurves.GetByName('secp256k1');
      LECDomainParams   := TECDomainParameters.Create(LCustomCurve.Curve,
      LCustomCurve.G, LCustomCurve.N, LCustomCurve.H, LCustomCurve.GetSeed);
      LKeyPairGenerator := TECKeyPairGenerator.Create('ECDSA');
      LKeyGenParams     := TECKeyGenerationParameters.Create(LECDomainParams, LSecureRandom);
      LKeyPairGenerator.Init(LKeyGenParams);
    
LKeyPair          := LKeyPairGenerator.GenerateKeyPair();
LPrivateKeyParams := LKeyPair.Private as IECPrivateKeyParameters; // for signing
LPublicKeyParams  := LKeyPair.Public as IECPublicKeyParameters; // for verifying
    
      PrivKey := LPrivateKeyParams.D.ToString(16);
      KoordX  := LPublicKeyParams.Q.Normalize.AffineXCoord.ToBigInteger.ToString(16);
      KoordY  := LPublicKeyParams.Q.Normalize.AffineYCoord.ToBigInteger.ToString(16);
```